# RxJava2 custom Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to understand how to bridge receiver-based events to the Reactive world.  I asked [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833118/wrapping-event-listeners-in-observables) and was pointed to a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659655/1953590).  The author of that answer (David Karnok) is extremely knowledgeable about RxJava, so I trust that his approach is a good one.

My concern is about the order things are done in the last few lines of `subscribeActual`.  I think I've got it right.  Here's my reasoning:

If the `Disposable` is disposed (i.e., the `Subscription` is canceled) during the call to `onSubscribe`, it's okay to call `onNext` with the last known location and potentially receive another location update when the listener is briefly subscribed because of Reactive Streams spec rule 2.8:

> A `Subscriber` MUST be prepared to receive one or more `onNext` signals after having called `Subscription.cancel()` . . .

If the `Disposable` is disposed during the call to `onSubscribe`, the `LocationListener` will be unregistered in `disposeActual` before it is registered, then unregistered again in `subscribeActual`.  Many Android APIs senselessly throw exceptions instead of simply doing nothing if you try to unregister a listener that isn't registered, but `LocationManager` isn't one of those.  If it were, I could put a try/catch in `disposeActual`.

Have I omitted anything?

```
public class GpsLocationObservable extends Observable<Location> {
    private final LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private final long mMinTime;
    private final float mMinDistance;

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    public GpsLocationObservable(final LocationManager locationManager, final long minTime, final float minDistance) {
        Params.requireNonNull(locationManager);
        Params.requireNonNegative(minTime);
        Params.requireNonNegative(minDistance);
        mLocationManager = locationManager;
        mMinTime = minTime;
        mMinDistance = minDistance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(final Observer<? super Location> observer) {
        final LocationListener listener = new LocationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                observer.onNext(location);
            }
        };

        final Disposable disposable = new AbstractDisposable() {
            @Override
            void disposeActual() {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
            }
        };

        observer.onSubscribe(disposable);
        final Location last = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(last != null) {
            observer.onNext(last);
        }
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mMinTime, mMinDistance, listener);
        if(disposable.isDisposed()) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

And my `AbstractDisposable`:

```
abstract public class AbstractDisposable implements Disposable {
    private final AtomicBoolean mDisposed = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        if(mDisposed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            disposeActual();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDisposed() {
        return mDisposed.get();
    }

    abstract void disposeActual();
}
```